# What is causing this enqueue snackbar error for notistack?

Tags: reactjs, debugging, undefined, typeerror, notistack

I'm trying to use the useSnack hook from notistack library but I keep getting this error

> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'enqueueSnackbar' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
import AlertContext from "../context/alert/alertContext";
import { SnackbarProvider, useSnackbar } from "notistack";

const Alerts = (props) => {
  const alertContext = useContext(AlertContext);
  // This line below is where the error seems to be
  const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();
  useEffect(() => {
    alertContext.msg !== "" &&
      enqueueSnackbar(alertContext.msg, {
        variant: alertContext.type,
      });
  }, [alertContext]);
  return <SnackbarProvider maxSnack={4}>{props.children}</SnackbarProvider>;
};

export default Alerts;
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`useSnackbar` hook accessible anywhere down the tree from `SnackbarProvider`.

So you cannot use it in the same component as `SnackbarProvier`.

```
import AlertContext from "../context/alert/alertContext";
import { SnackbarProvider } from "notistack";

const Alerts = (props) => {
  const alertContext = useContext(AlertContext);
  const providerRef = React.useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    alertContext.msg !== "" &&
      providerRef.current.enqueueSnackbar(alertContext.msg, {
        variant: alertContext.type,
      });
  }, [alertContext]);
  return <SnackbarProvider ref={providerRef} maxSnack={4}>
       {props.children}
       </SnackbarProvider>;
};

export default Alerts;
```

Comment: I moved the SnackbarProvider to index.js og my react app and it started working in all components of my app, very helpful answer

Answer (score 3):

Wrap you index file with SnapBar provider:

**index.js**

```
import { SnackbarProvider } from "notistack";

const Index = () => (
    <SnackbarProvider maxSnack={1} preventDuplicate>
        index
    </SnackbarProvider>
)

export default Index
```

**jsx file**

```
import { useSnackbar } from "notistack";

const Logs = () => {
    const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

    const handler = () => {
        enqueueSnackbar(`Successful.`, { variant: "success" });
    };

    return <span onClick={handler}>"Logs loading"</span>;
};

export default Logs;
```